# Listing sub-categories based on category - pull from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have separated products by category and sub-category.
With a query and while loop I am able to echo out all the categories in a list correctly.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE `enabled`='1'");

while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo '$query_row[catname]';
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to have the sub-category names listed under their respective category name:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE `enabled`='1'");

while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo '<h1>'.$query_row["catname"].'</h1>';

     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE `catid`='$query_row[catid]'");

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
     echo '$row["subcatname"]';
     }
}
```

What I am getting is a list of every category (thats great) - but under it a list of every sub-category. I only need the sub-categories that go with their own category. Should I use a for loop somewhere? what is the best solution?

End result should be:

```
CARS
mazda
chevy
toyota

BIKES
yamaha
harley
suzuki
honda

BATTERIES
duracel
energizer
```

As it is now. im getting

```
CARS
mazda
chevy
toyota
yamaha
harley
suzuki
honda
duracel
energizer

BIKES
mazda
chevy
toyota
yamaha
harley
suzuki
honda
duracel
energizer

BATTERIES
mazda
chevy
toyota
yamaha
harley
suzuki
honda
duracel
energizer
```

Comment: what do you mean by "I only need the sub-categories that go with their own category" ? what kind of sub-categories do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE catid='$query_row[catid]'");`

to

`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE catid='" . $query_row["catid"] . "'");`

Comment: same result. no change

Comment: If catid in subcategory matches catid in category, this code could only result in the list you show when all the subcategories exists for all the categories in the database.

Comment: Maybe you can dump an structure and data export of those tables here.

Comment: catid in subcategory only matches catid in category when the subcategory entries are in the same category. i.e. mazda, chevy, toyota have catid=1, while duracel and energizer have catid=3 etc.

Comment: What happens when you use `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE catid='3'");`? If that gives the right results, there is something wrong with `$query_row["catid"]`. Else there must be something wrong with the data in your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE `enabled`='1'");

while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo '<h1>'.$query_row["catname"].'</h1>';

     $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT catid FROM subcategory WHERE `catname`='$query_row[catname]'");
     while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)){

     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE `catid`='row1[catid]'");

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
     echo '$row["subcatname"]';
     }
     }
     }
```

try this one.

Comment: catname isn't the same as catid so $sql will return false.